# what URL call this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

have function like this:

```
this.rmSaveParam = function(index, value, responseMethod, errorMethod) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        url: this.destination_ + (updater.currentDevice_ ? "rmNewParam?uid=" + encodeURIComponent(updater.currentDevice_) + "&" : "rmNewParam?") + "newParamIndex=" + encodeURIComponent(index) + "&newParamValue=" + encodeURIComponent(value),
        success: responseMethod,
        error: errorMethod
    });
    return false;
}
```

`this.destination_` = https://www.econet24.com/
`updater.currentDevice_` = C6ZPLELPP36R45624503480
`index` = 56
`value` = 67

I try to guess how the URL will look like.
I try something like this but it's probably wrong (too much question marks?): "https://www.econet24.com/C6ZPLELPP36R45624503480rmNewParam?uid=C6ZPLELPP36R45624503480&rmNewParam?newParamIndex=56&newParamValue=67"

Comment: Why not figure it out with code instead of guessing?

Comment: Oh my. That's a horrible mess of manual stuff that should just be a `data: {}` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy enough to figure out. No need to guess!

```js
const destination = 'https://www.econet24.com/';
const currentDevice = 'C6ZPLELPP36R45624503480';
const index = 56;
const value = 67;


const url = destination
            + (currentDevice 
                 ? "rmNewParam?uid=" + encodeURIComponent(currentDevice) + "&"
                 : "rmNewParam?")
            + "newParamIndex=" + encodeURIComponent(index)
            + "&newParamValue=" + encodeURIComponent(value);

console.log(url);
```

There is a better, and much cleaner, way to do this.

```js
this.rmSaveParam = function(index, value, responseMethod, errorMethod) {
    const queryParams = {
        newParamIndex: index,
        newParamValue: value
    };

    if (updater.currentDevice_) {
        queryParams.uid = updater.currentDevice_;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        url: this.destination_ + rmNewParam,
        data: queryParams,
        success: responseMethod,
        error: errorMethod
    });
    return false;
}
```

Notice the lack of `encodeURIComponent`, this is done for you automatically.